# Asp.NET / My user table keep user's location which has a geography (type) column.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, google-maps, geography

My user table keep user's location (latitude and longitude) which has a geography (type) column.(I convert it geography type when insert). And I want to send latitude and longitude with my linq query and return users which location near by me

How I can created this stored procedure.. And How I can send latitude and longitude with my linq query asp.net mvc

My latitude and longitude properties are decimal

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide what you have so far code wise and hopefully someone can answer your question.

Comment: apparently you want to do a lot, but you have not done anything yet